# Android ¿Cómo poner en orden aleatorio algunos elementos de un array?

Tags: android, array, random

Tengo una App de preguntas de examen de carrera donde cada una es un array. El [0] es la pregunta y desde el [1] al [5] son las opciones de respuesta, que me gustaría ponerlas en orden aleatorio para que no siempre salgan igual y evitar que se respondan de memoria. Lo tengo así y funciona perfectamente pero necesito ayuda para el orden aleatorio. Gracias!!

```
  private void preguntas() {
      String mistring = preguntas_array[pregunta_pantalla];
      final String[] parts = mistring.split(";");

 TextView QuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(array_respuestas[0]);
        QuestionView.setText(parts[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            Button boton_resp = (Button) findViewById(array_respuestas[i]);
            boton_resp.setText(parts[i]);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es poner los elementos 1 a 5 dentro de un `ArrayList` y usar la linea de código `Collections.shuffle(arreglo);`. Esto ordenaría aleatoriamente el arreglo en su lugar. Para incluir la pregunta, puedes simplemente anadir ese valor al principio del nuevo `ArrayList` con `arreglo.add(0, pregunta);`.

Comment: Lo he hecho pero la App se cerraba sola al entrar en esta activity

Answer (score 0):

Existen varios métodos, teniendo el array de strings puedes usar este metodo:

```
    private static String [] shuffleArray(String[] array)
{
    int index;
    String temp;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
        temp = array[index];
        array[index] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
return array;
}
```

Este método obtiene un valor aleatoriamente  partir del array original, y puede ser llamado de esta forma:

```
String[] nuevoOrden = shuffleArray(parts);
```

Comment: Lo siento, no sé por qué me sale también la pregunta entre las respuestas haciendo lo que me has dicho.